# How to get livereload.js working on localhost, error -> ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: gruntjs, livereload

I'm trying to get my page to refresh automatically with grunt watch and when to do this on index.html:

```
<script src="//localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>
```

I am getting the error `http://localhost:35729/livereload.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

how can I fix this?

Comment: This error is normally thrown by Adblocker extensions installed in the browser , try disabling browser extensions and then see if it works

Comment: @PrayagVerma THX But I still have the same issue

Comment: @PrayagVerma can I disable all extensions for a page at once?

Comment: I disabled them all except the disable all extension. but still get same error

Comment: how are you the files when you get the error? Local Apache, grunt-connect, someting else?

Answer (score 5):

try this out :

don't use this :

```
<script src="//localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>
```

use this :

```
 <script src="http://localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>
```

i hope it will work